# wordpress: how to remove category name from browser bar?

Tags: php, wordpress

When user browse trough categories browser bar displays "Category_name - title". Like this:[image]

Exhibitions is the name of the browsing category and "test title" is a title which I set up in my setting. How can I remove this Exhibitions part and remain just a title?

Comment: this is set in the theme, modify your theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two standard places that this could be coming from:

1. In Settings > Permalinks, see if you're using a custom structure with %category% as one of the parameters
2. In your theme's PHP files. You could have archive.php or category.php or index.php, depending on the theme. In one of those, you should find what's being output as the page title. It will probably include `<?php wp_title(''); ?>` This is a list of a lot of other parameters that it might be pulling: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/  You also might find `<?php single_cat_title(); ?>` somewhere. If you can't find it, search the file for the word "category" to track it down.